# How to make java POJO for this json?

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb, pojo

I'm curious about how to make a POJO when the key values are numeric as given in the given JSON object.

```
{
    "id" : 1,

    "options": {
        "1": "a",
        "2": "b",
        "3": "c",
        "4": "e"
    }
}
```

as you can see options have numeric values as a key, so how to make java POJO out of it, as a variable name cannot be numeric.

Comment: Use `Map<Integer, String> options`

Comment: "*as you can see options have numeric values as a key*"  - Nope. Those are `string`s (in JSON terms) since this is how [the JSON standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) defines names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this

```
public class MyPojo {

    private int id;
    private Map<Integer, String> options;

}
```